Создать запрос на обновление данных в таблице на основе данных из другой таблицы
Есть 2 таблицы:
Клиенты:
Код / Счётчик
Фамилия
Имя
Отчество
Роль

И
Отправители:
Код / Числовой
Фамилия
Имя
Отчество
Роль

Надо написать запрос на обновление, чтобы все поля из таблицы Клиенты переносились в таблицу Отправители, а новые добавлялись. Условие переноса/добавления: при значении поля роль "Отправитель".

Детализируйте ваш вопрос и лучше с примерами

чтобы все поля из таблицы Клиенты переносились в таблицу Отправители То есть из исходной перенесённые записи - удалить? А что делать, если запись уже есть, но отличается - перезаписывать? И, наверное, не "все поля", что предполагает работу со структурой таблиц, а "значения всех полей"...
